# quicksort code understanding

Tags: c, text, quicksort

i have a quicksort code that is supposed to run on the text "B A T T A J U S" (ignore blanks). But i dont seem to understand the code that well.

```
 void quicksort (itemType a[], int l, int r)
 {
    int i, j; itemType v;
    if (r>l)
    {
       v = a[r]; i = l-1; j = r;
       for (;;)
        {
           while (a[++i] < v);
           while (a[--j] >= v);
           if (i >= j) break;
           swap(a,i,j);
        }

        swap(a,i,r);
        quicksort(a,l,i-1);
        quicksort(a,i+1,r);

    }

 }
```

i can explain what i understand: the first if check if l < r which in this case it is since, s is greater than b. THen i get alittle confused: v is set to be equal to a[r], does this mean S? since S is all the way to the right? then l is set to outside the "array" since its -1. (so its undefined, i assume) then j is set to be equal to r, but is that the posision r? as in S?

I kinda dont understand what values are set to what, if the a[r] = the letter in the posision or the or anything else. Hopefully some1 can explain me how the first swap works, so i hopefully can learn this?

Comment: Why don't you print out all of the intermediate states, just after `swap` call?

Comment: "s is greater than b" <- No, s' index is greater than b's index.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but what language is this? It looks like C but with one-based indexing. Unless `v=a[r]` is a typo of `v=a[r-1]`

Comment: Also, your second `while` loop should be over `j`, not over `i`

Comment: this is c++ and this code is what we get handed on our exam with a text like i mentioned above, and we gotta write down for each change in the text to prove we understand the code.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I don't see what makes it appear to have 1-based indexing, but I did have to look carefully to distinguish the variable `l` from the number `1`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger `v=a[r]` does.

Comment: i am supposed to get this answer after the code is finished: http://pastebin.com/P7iuUM8E

Comment: @MadPhysicist `v=a[r]` is fine if `r` is the index of the last element of the (sub)array, which appears to be consistent with the recursive calls.

Comment: @JohnBollinger. True. I had been reading it as one-past-the-end. Stupid habit.

Comment: Also, I am pretty sure you want `a[--j] <= v`.

Comment: i read the code over again and i edited it to [--j], but i still dont understand anything of this code tbh :/

Comment: I am working on an answer. This is actually a pretty nice implementation of QS.

Comment: okay thanks for the help. the task tells us to use that code on the text mentioned in the thread start, but it also tell us to write down for every recursive sorting on the involved letters. as in the pastbinlink in the comments, which contains the answers

Comment: I will not do your assignment for you, but I would be glad to explain it so that you have enough information to do it yourself.

Comment: thats perfect, i am not after the answer since i already know the answer... and this is just example task of how the exam will be not assigment. i just need som pinpoints on how the code works so i can find out the answer on my own :)

Answer (score 1):

It is probably better to start with an understanding of the QuickSort algorithm, and then see how the code corresponds to it, than to study the code to try to figure out how QuickSort works.  Basic QuickSort (which is what you have) is in fact a pretty simple algorithm.  To sort an array `A`:

1. If the length of `A` is less than 2 then the array is already sorted.  Otherwise,
2. Select any element of `A` to be a "pivot element".
3. Rearrange the other elements as needed so that all those that are less than the pivot are at the beginning of `A`, and those that are greater than or equal to the pivot are at the end.  (This particular version also puts the pivot itself between the two, which is common but not strictly necessary; it could simply be included in the upper subarray, and the algorithm would still work.)
4. Apply the QuickSort procedure to each of the two sub-arrays produced by (3).

Your particular code chooses the right-most element of each (sub)array as the pivot element, and at step (4) it excludes the pivot from the sub-arrays to be recursively sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Quick sort works by separating your array into a "left" subarray which contains only values stricly less than an arbitrarily chosen a pivot value and a "right" subarray that contains only elements that are greater than or equal to the pivot. Once the array has been divided like this, each of the two subarrays are sorted using the same algorithm. Here is how this applies to your code:

`v = a[r]` sets the pivot value to the last element in the array. This works well since the array is presumably unsorted to begin with, so `a[r]` is as good a value as any.

`while(a[++i] < v) ;` keeps stopping at the first element of the left sub-array that is greater than or equal to the pivot, `v`. When this loop ends, `i` is the index of an element that should be in the right sub-array rather than the left.

`while(a[--j] >= v) ;` does the same thing, except that it stops at the last element of the right sub-array that is strictly less than the pivot, `v`. When this loop ends, `j` is the index of an element that should be in the left sub-array rather than the right.

Whenever we find a pair of elements that are in the wrong sub-arrays, we swap them.

When all of the elements in the array are sorted (`i` meets `j`), we swap the pivot with the element at index `i` (which is now guaranteed to be in the right sub-array).

Since the pivot is guaranteed to be in the right position (left sub-array is strictly less and right sub-array is greater than or equal), we need to sort the sub-arrays but not the pivot. That is why the recursive calls use indices `l,i-1` and `i+1,r`, leaving the pivot at index `i`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't offer a solution in that exact form.  That code is overly complicated in my thinking.

Also not sure if what I'm proposing is a bubble sort, or modified bubble, but to me just easier.  My added comment is that quicksort() is calling itself, therefore it is recursive.  Not good in my book for something as simple as a sort.  This all depends on what you need for size and efficiency.  If you're sorting many terms, then my proposed sort is not the best.

```
for(i = 0; i < (n - 1); i++) {
    for(j = (i + 1); j < n; j++) {
        if(value[i] > value[j]) {
            tmp = value[i];
            value[i] = value[j];
            value[j] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Where

- `n` is the number of total elements.
- `i`, `j`, and `tmp` are integers
- `value[]` is an array of integers to sort